# Call a stored procedure, into another stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a procedure, that insert a line into one of my table.

After the INSERT in the procedure, I want to find all the lines into another table, and then, call the insert procedure of the second table.

So I have all the first procedure that works fine

```
P_INSERT_TABLE1

INSERT INTO TABLE1

...
COMMIT;

FOR record_po IN (SELECT C3, ...
                    FROM T_TABLE2
                    WHERE id = v_id)
LOOP
      P_INSERT_TABLE2(record_po.C3, ...);
END LOOP;
```

All "in parameters" for P_INSERT_TABLE2 are VARCHAR2, so I make a "to_char" for each column are not varchar2 :

```
P_INSERT_TABLE2(pi_id,
                      record_po.C3,
                      record_po.C4,
                      record_po.C5,
                      record_po.C6,
                      record_po.C7,
                      to_char(record_po.C8, 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Here, pi_id, is one of the in parameters of P_INSERT_TABLE1, in VARCHAR2.

So now, I have this error message :

```
Erreur(357,1): PLS-00306: number or args types wrong in the call of P_INSERT_TABLE2
```

I don't understand, why P_INSERT_TABLE2 don't accept parameters, while there are all the good types in the good order?

If I call the procedure like "`call P_INSERT_TABLE2(...)`" I have an error like :

```
Erreur(357,9): PLS-00103: Symbol "P_INSERT_TABLE2" instead one of this symbols :     := . ( @ % ; immediate Symbole ":=" 

create or replace
PROCEDURE P_INSERT_TABLE2 (
  pi_id          IN VARCHAR2
  ,pi_C3         IN VARCHAR2
  ,pi_C4         IN VARCHAR2
  ,pi_C5         IN VARCHAR2
  ,pi_C6         IN VARCHAR2
  ,pi_C7         IN VARCHAR2
  ,pi_C8         IN VARCHAR2
  ,pmessage      OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2  
)
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Could you add the declaration for P-INSERT-TABLE2, please? BTW: Please don't use "-" in procedure names - that's terribly confusing; I don't believe this is your real code, since table names and procedure names containing "-" will not be accepted by Oracle unless properly quoted.

Comment: Yes, the code is too long, so I replace name colum by C1 etc... And table name and procedure with generic names.

Comment: How about your OUT parameter? Are you sending that when you call from P_INSERT_TABLE1?

Comment: I also have the out paramater for P_INSERT_TABLE1. It is not called. I just put a text into it. I have 7 IN parameters in P_INSERT_TABLE2, and i Give 7 IN parameters when i call IT;

Comment: @Jean You have to define it in the function call to P_INSERT_TABLE2 regardless of whether you want to actually use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration of `P_INSERT_TABLE2` is invalid.  You can't have 5 input parameters all named `pi_C4`.  Since you're not getting a compilation error creating that procedure, I'll guess that this was a bug that was introduced posting the question here rather than something that is actually in the code.

According to the declaration of `P_INSERT_TABLE2`, the procedure takes 7 input parameters and one output parameter.  In the code you posted, you appear to be passing in 7 input parameters but you are not passing in a variable for the output parameter.  It appears that you need something like

```
P_INSERT_TABLE2(pi_id,
                record_po.C3,
                record_po.C4,
                record_po.C5,
                record_po.C6,
                record_po.C7,
                to_char(record_po.C8, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
                <<some local variable for the output parameter>> );
```

Beyond the syntax errors, I am extremely dubious when I see someone taking a perfectly good `DATE`, casting it to a string, and then passing that to a procedure.  That implies either that `P_INSERT_TABLE2` is going to turn around and convert the string back to a date, which means that you're doing extra work and have introduced additional points where the conversions can fail, or that you are going to write the string representation of a date to a table.  Neither of these implications are good.

I am also highly dubious of any procedure that has an `OUT` parameter named `pMessage`.  That tends to imply that you're not using exceptions properly and that you're passing an error message back rather than throwing an exception if your code encounters an error.  That virtually always leads to much more brittle code that is much more difficult to debug than when you use proper exceptions.

Comment: Indeed, I convert string back after, but this is because I need P_INSERT_TABLE2 in others cases. So I must to do it. And I using exception, but pmessage can be good or wrong, so i display it into my silverlight view(succes message or fail message). That's why I use OUT parameters, and Exception.

Comment: Thank you that works fine now. I was thinking i don''t needed to have the OUT parameter in a call. Now i will know it.